# Connect Ipython Notebook to PyCharm Python console

Tags: python, django, pycharm, ipython, jupyter-notebook

PyCharm 4.5.4 has an option "Python Console" (Tools -> Python Console) which runs a Python interpreter with proper paths and allows to debug Django projects (for example). Aslo it has an option of using IPython if it is present, and the question is if it is possible to connect an IPython Notebook or QtConsole to this interpreter?

I've tried using `%connect_info` and `%qtconsole`, but it doesn't work, probably that means that the kernel is not running (like if I were to run just `$ ipython`). If so can it be started without a lot of trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be easier than I thought.

So, in order to use IPython Notebook to debug local Django App in the Django Console, you need to add `django-extensions` library to your project's interpreter, append it to settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS`, then go to the "Terminal" tab in PyCharm (its options are in `Settings -> Tools -> Terminal`), navigate to the folder with manage.py if you are not there, and use a command

`python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`